# Проблема с допускам на страницу

Tags: php

У меня есть страница, что-бы в нее войти нужно авторизоваться, но если тупо ввести адрес этой страницы, то не надо авторизоваться,и любой человек может просто войти с любого сайтаю

Как сделать так, что-бы если пользователь не авторизовался он не мог посещать ту страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй сессии и куки